# Let $X_1\sim Laplace(0,\sqrt{1/2})$ and $X_2 \sim Laplace(1/2,\sqrt{1/2})$. Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, laplacian

Let $X_1\sim Laplace(0,\sqrt{1/2})$ and $X_2 \sim Laplace(1/2,\sqrt{1/2})$. Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent?

I understand that in case of independence, the joint pdf is the product of the marginal pdfs. I know how to find marginals from joint pdf but I'm not sure how to find $f_{X_1,X_2}$. Also, can I use the expectation to prove independence?

Comment: Not enough information to tell.

Comment: @Ian why is that? what are the missing info?

Comment: Where does dependence / independence come into the picture?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I don't get your question. These are two RVs with Laplace distributions of different parameter. I'm trying to find if they are independent or not.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask this. You cannot determine whether two RVs are independent just by looking at their individual distributions.

Comment: @m_t_ what are the other information needed? I'm confused.

Comment: You have to know something about their joint distribution, for example their joint pdf

Comment: If $x$ ia a real variable and $z$ is a  complex variable are they indpendent variables? Does not make sense right? $x$ could be real part of $z$ or it could be independent of $z$. You have to knowledge of joint distribution to say if two random variables are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*People in the comments section are trying to explain that we really don't have enough information. Maybe this convinces you...*

I construct $X_1$ and $X_2$, with the same distributions you have in the question, which are dependent in one case and independent in another. Let $Y\sim \text{Laplace}(0,\sqrt{1/2})$. I give you two situations.

**Dependent.**
Define $X_1 = Y$ and $X_2=Y+\frac 1 2$. Now we have that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent, you see why?

**Independent.**
Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent versions of $Y$. Now define $X_1=Y_1$ and $X_2=Y_2+\frac 1 2$. In this case they are independent, you see why?

So, we really can't tell anything about dependence if you just tell us the marginal distributions.